# Symfony2: Twig error on dumping assets in prod

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Attempting to dump prod assets results in

> [Twig_Error_Loader]   The
> "/www2.projectmana.org/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/views" directory does not exist.

using command

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

in a chroot environment on a shared host.  The directory does indeed exist and its contents can be listed by this non-root user so it's unlikely to be a rights issue.

#### Update: command results:

```
projectmana@vhost4:/home/projectmana % ls -l /www2.projectmana.org/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/views
ls: /www2.projectmana.org/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/views: No such file or directory
projectmana@vhost4:/home/projectmana % cd www2.projectmana.org
projectmana@vhost4:/home/projectmana/www2.projectmana.org % ls -l vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/views                     total 4
drwxr-xr-x  2 projectmana  projectmana  47 Oct 26 16:14 Form
drwxr-xr-x  2 projectmana  projectmana   6 Oct 26 16:14 FormTable
projectmana@vhost4:/home/projectmana/www2.projectmana.org %
```

Comment: Please show the output of `ls -l /www2.projectmana.org/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/views` command.

Comment: @n.1: Command results included above.  Are they the result of the chroot environment?  I invoke the dump command from the `...mana.org` directory.

Comment: This is interesting that the `ls -l` gives different results from the directory you execute it. But I don't understand why. Sorry.

Comment: Just learned from ISP host that the shell is NOT chroot'd.  If the shell was would the `assetic:dump` command work properly?

Comment: Your `www2.projectmana.org/` is in the `/home/projectmana/` directory. This explains the error in your question.

Comment: So the key is the `/` at the beginning of your path. Did you set it somewhere?

Comment: @n.1: The default setting of kernel.root_dir is unchanged. In a test I added `'dir' => $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir()` to a controller.  The `dir` in a template showed `/www2.../app`.  This suggests to me that the shell command and prod see the same root so chroot'ing the shell command will not make any difference.

Comment: Got the same error and in my case this command (run it in the root dir of symfony project): `rm -frv app/cache/prod && rm -frv app/cache/dev && php app/console cache:clear && php app/console cache:clear -e prod` worked and I could run `php app/console assetic:dump -e prod -v` and assets were generated